# OpenVPN with systemd: Ask for password with pkttyagent

Tags: systemd, openvpn

openvpn has the ability to ask for passwords and systemd can prompt on the command line for it:

```
# systemctl start openvpn@name
Enter Auth Username: asd
Enter Auth Password: ***
```

Is it also possible to get GUI prompt like `pkttyagent`? systemctl opens such one when asking for the sudo password using the pkttyagent, like this:

[image: systemctl sudo pkttyagent]